# Extract factor column from data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

My data frame is breaking when i extract some rows from a factor column:

```
data.df = data.frame(x = factor(letters[1:10]))
data.temp = data.df[1:3, ]
print(data.temp)
```

How can i avoid that? I need to column name to be kept also. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can add argument `drop=FALSE` to keep data as data frame.

```
 data.df = data.frame(x = factor(letters[1:10]))     
 data.temp = data.df[1:3, ,drop=FALSE]
 print(data.temp)
  x
1 a
2 b
3 c
```